# Paste multiple columns into a single column but remove any NA, blank, or duplicate values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(SOURCES1 = c("123 Name, 123 Rd, City, State", 
                               "354 Name, 354 Rd, City, State",
                               NA,"",""),
                  SOURCES2 = c("","",
                               "321 Name, 321 Rd, City, State", 
                               "678 Name, 678 Rd, City, State",
                               ""),
                  SOURCES3 = c("","",NA,
                               "678 Name, 678 Rd, City, State", 
                               NA),
                  SOURCES4 = c("","","",NA,NA),
                  SOURCES5 = c("","","",NA,NA))
```

And I'm looking to produce a column that looks like this:

```
"123 Name, 123 Rd, City, State"
"354 Name, 354 Rd, City, State"
"321 Name, 321 Rd, City, State"
"678 Name, 678 Rd, City, State"
NA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `coalesce` after converting the blanks (`""`) to `NA`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(na_if(as.character(.), ''))) %>% 
   transmute(SOURCE = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))))
#                         SOURCE
#1 123 Name, 123 Rd, City, State
#2 354 Name, 354 Rd, City, State
#3 321 Name, 321 Rd, City, State
#4 678 Name, 678 Rd, City, State
#5                          <NA>
```

---

Or use `invoke` from `purrr`

```
dat %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(na_if(as.character(.), ''))) %>% 
   transmute(SOURCE = invoke(coalesce, .))
#                         SOURCE
#1 123 Name, 123 Rd, City, State
#2 354 Name, 354 Rd, City, State
#3 321 Name, 321 Rd, City, State
#4 678 Name, 678 Rd, City, State
#5                          <NA>
```

---

Or with `pnax` from `base R`

```
do.call(pmax, c(lapply(dat, function(x) replace(as.character(x), 
          x=="", NA)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks much!

Comment: @SCDCE It evaluates the symbol list and applies the function `coalesce`